# Copy all files contained in a *.mpcpl (Media Player Classic Playlist) file

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, music, playlists, media-player-classic

I have a Windows Media Player Classic Playlist file with thousands of songs selected from many folders on HDD. I want to copy all of those files to my USB flash drive.

How can I do that? Is there an app allowing to do it? Or maybe even Windows Media Player Classic can take care of this task?

Comment: What OS are you using? Typically music files are stored in the users profile directory, once you locate the actual files a simple copy and paste will work.

Comment: @Moab: I'm using Windows. Those thousands of files in the playlist are scattered around dozens of folders and it will be complete waste of time to do it manually. I'm searching for a tool that can automatically read the mpcpl playlist and copy songs from it to a certain location.

Comment: How did they get scattered, this is not normal. Usually they are all in one folder, even if there are hundreds of folders in that one folder it is easy to copy, I do it all the time and have wasted no time, I would have had it done by now.

Comment: Windows what????? FYI, asking for software recommendations here is off topic and this question may be closed.

Comment: @Moab: Example: you drop all the music you have to MPC playlist and then remove some songs you don't want to be there. That way playlist gets contained only part of files that you keep in your physical folders. Suppose you don't want to copy all files in that folders - you only want to copy files you have left in the playlist.

Comment: @Moab: Is the way we can achieve the task really depends on the certain Windows version? I doubt any Windows has built-in support of *.mpcpl files. But anyway, I have access to any of Win7, Win 2012R2, Win 8.1. Sorry, I'm not requesting any particular tool for this job in the question. If this is achievable using some trick with MPC itself etc. - it'd be pretty fine too.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this without 3rd party software, and not sure there is any that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you only want to copy songs that you dragged to your playlist, there is a software for that called [Amok Playlist Copy](http://www.amok.am/en/freeware/amok_playlist_copy/).

In order to copy your music using that tool you will have to:

- Save the Playlist in m3u
- Load it in the tool
- Click copy files from playlist

Comment: McAfee and Norton say they don't know whether this site is safe.

Comment: @Scott Hum maybe because it's unpopular? Avast didn't give any warning when visiting the site nor unzipping the program.